# How to get the unique results from Lucene index?

Tags: duplicates, lucene

I am trying to search from lucene index . I want to get the unique results but its returning the duplicate results also. I searched on google and found it can be done with the help of a collector. How can I achieve this?

I am using the following code:

```
File outputdir= new File("path upto lucene directory");
Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(outputdir);
IndexSearcher= new IndexSearcher(directory,true);

QueryParser queryparser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "keyword", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));

Query query = queryparser.parse("central");

topdocs = indexSearcher.search(query, maxhits);
ScoreDoc[] score = topdocs.scoreDocs;
int length = score.length;
```

Comment: What's your document and field structure?? Can you post it??

Comment: What's a "duplicate" result? Are you indexing identical data several times? Do you get several identical document identifiers in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a field named for example "duplicate" and set the value to "true" on indexing time when it already has a duplicate in the index.

So you can search for

```
Query query = queryparser.parse("central -duplicate:true");
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you indexing content before each search ?

If so, I suggest you to separate indexing code and searching code because if you launch this script several times without deleting the index folder Lucene doesn't overwrite the index but add again the content to the index. I think this is why you get duplicates results.

Answer (score 2):

You could:

1. When indexing - add a field that will be unique for each document.
2. When searching - use DuplicateFilter

`DuplicateFilter df = new DuplicateFilter("Key");
    df.setKeepMode(DuplicateFilter.KM_USE_LAST_OCCURRENCE);
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, df, 10);`

Comment: df.KeepMode = DuplicateFilter.KM_USE_LAST_OCCURRENCE

Comment: Duplicate filter is no longer available since Lucene 6.0.0 Hence this solution will not work now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem in two ways.

First, you can divide your indices into two parts. The one is original and the other one is copy. You can do this work in the indexing step. And then you can decide how to search by yourself.

Second, you can write a collector and use it as a param for `IndexSearcher.search`. The `collector` should extends `TopDocsCollector` or `TopFieldDocCollector` and overwrite the `collect` method. In your own `collect` method,I think you can use a `Set` to save the content for the `doc` which the score is larger than 0, and then use `super.collect(doc,score)` to finish the original steps in Lucene. If the content has been in set we can stop the Lucene step and deal with next doc.